# Como plotar grafico de barra com matplotlib + Counter()

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

Olá!

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico de barras do livro Data Science do Zero, mas está bem diferente do livro.
Obs: o livro é em Python 2 e estou utilizando o Python 3

No livro, está:

```
from collections import Counter
friends_counts = Counter(num_friends)
xs = range(101)
ys = [friends_counts[x] for x in xs]
plt.bar(xs,ys)
plt.axis([0, 101, 0, 25])
plt.title('Histograma da contagem de amigos')
plt.xlabel('# de amigos')
plt.ylabel('# de pessoas')
plt.show()
```

O que resulta em:

[image: Histograma de Contagem de amigos]

Já o meu, está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável "friends_counts" armazena:

```
friends_counts
Counter({100: 1, 49: 1, 41: 1, 40: 1, 25: 1})
```

Nao estou conseguindo chegar no resultado do livro...
Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Olhando pelo código, já que a variável `friends_counts` armazena somente `Counter({100: 1, 49: 1, 41: 1, 40: 1, 25: 1})`, o resultado que você teve foi o esperado. Pelo gráfico gerado no livro, essa variável tem bem mais valores.

Comment: Se você olhar no livro, a descrição correta para num_friends é [100, 49, 41, 40, 25, **e muitos mais**]. O problema está no "e muitos mais". No capítulo 1 há uma explicação que se trata de um problema de grafo (quem é amigo de quem) e mostra como calcular a lista completa de amigos (que tem 204 elementos).